# Setting Colors For Positive and Negative Values in a Scatter Plot with Custom Colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

For a scatter plot in Matplotlib, I want show positive (y) values in green color, and negative (y) values in red color. If I set the value z>0, and put this in the argument of (c), by default it does give me 2 different colors for the positive values and negative values. But i want to change those colors to my choice of Green for Positive, and Red for Negative. How can I do this?

```py
x = [4, 5, 11, 15] 
y = [17, -14, 13, -19]

z = y > 0

plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)

plt.show()
```

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. I saw your question history on your profile and you haven't ticked at least one question as correct. I remind you this because some users often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: thanks, i will take note of that.  i defiinitley do the upvotes. For correct answers, as it states in the link you put, it suggest to only mark as correct if you may feel it answers correctly as you do so, and in my perspective if applied and proves to be. It also states do not fell pressured, as more answers can flow through, which would make responses even better for all perspectives. Definitley , if one feels it is resolved, marking "answered" is correct step to take.

Answer (score 1):

You can rearrange your data and split into positive and negative values. As part of this answer I suggest you to use `np.array` instead of using the dtype `list` because it is much easier to use indices in this case

```
import numpy as np
# data
x = np.array([ 4, 5, 11, 15 ])
y = np.array([ 17, -14, 13, -19 ])
z = 0

valid_pos = []  # preallocate appending variable
valid_neg = []
for i in range(0, x.shape[0]):  # 0 for number of lines, 1 for number of columns
    if y[i] >= z:
        valid_pos.append(i)
    elif y[i] < z:
        valid_neg.append(i)
x_pos = x[valid_pos]  # rearrange your data
y_pos = y[valid_pos]
x_neg = x[valid_neg]
y_neg = y[valid_neg]

# plotting figure
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x_pos, y_pos, c='g')
plt.scatter(x_neg, y_neg, c='r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful and helped solve what my objective was. thanks for the insight on numpy array.  But do you know of a way to do this with just the "c" argument like i showed above ? Because i assume with just using the "c" argument like i did above, it is a lot less lines of code than writing a for loop. I just want to make sure, if it cannot be done with c argument or not.

Comment: yes it does work, you just have to define `x` and `y` as `np.array`, then you can use your code above. The only thing which still has to be defined is your desired colour red and green. I don't know how it works actually but maybe I find something :)